# Is there a way to monitor all events sent to the libnotify module?

Tags: libnotify

Is there a way to monitor all events sent to the libnotify module?

I am trying to debug faulty sound notifications from Thunderbird, and I am hoping that if the way Thunderbird links with sounds is faulty, I can at least play my own sound.

I am using Ubuntu 12.04 with KDE.

Comment: I found this AU Q&A titled: [Listening to incoming libnotify notifications using DBus](http://askubuntu.com/questions/89279/listening-to-incoming-libnotify-notifications-using-dbus/190759#190759)

Answer (score 0):

I usually turn to `incron` to manage inotify tasks:

```
sudo apt-get install incron
```

Create an incron file in /etc/incron.d:

```
echo '/tmp IN_ALL_EVENTS echo "$$ $@ $# $% $&"' > /etc/incron.d/watch-dir-tmp
```

That will dump ALL events in /tmp to /var/log/syslog:

`date > /tmp/date`

```
Apr 30 21:29:26 vault incrond[10144]: (system::watch-dir-tmp) CMD (echo "$ /tmp date IN_MODIFY 2")
Apr 30 21:29:26 vault incrond[10144]: (system::watch-dir-tmp) CMD (echo "$ /tmp date IN_OPEN 32")
Apr 30 21:29:26 vault incrond[10144]: (system::watch-dir-tmp) CMD (echo "$ /tmp date IN_MODIFY 2")
Apr 30 21:29:26 vault incrond[10144]: (system::watch-dir-tmp) CMD (echo "$ /tmp date IN_CLOSE_WRITE 8")
```

`cat /tmp/date`

```
Apr 30 21:29:33 vault incrond[10144]: (system::watch-dir-tmp) CMD (echo "$ /tmp date IN_OPEN 32")
Apr 30 21:29:33 vault incrond[10144]: (system::watch-dir-tmp) CMD (echo "$ /tmp date IN_ACCESS 1")
Apr 30 21:29:33 vault incrond[10144]: (system::watch-dir-tmp) CMD (echo "$ /tmp date IN_CLOSE_NOWRITE 16")
```

`rm /tmp/date`

```
Apr 30 21:29:40 vault incrond[10144]: (system::watch-dir-tmp) CMD (echo "$ /tmp date IN_DELETE 512")
```

Comment: The question is about libnotify rather than inotify unless libnotify events can be tracked via inotify. It it is a mistake, I will create a similar question for inotify and you can place this answer there